# Why is such a vector guaranteed to exist?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Theorem::
>
> Let $M$ be a symmetric matrix and let $x$ be a non-zero vector that maximizes the
> **Rayleigh quotient** with respect to $M$. Then, $x$ is an eigenvector of $M$ with eigenvalue equal to the
> Rayleigh quotient. Moreover, this eigenvalue is the largest eigenvalue of M.

On seeing the theorem the first question is why will such an eigen vector exist?

Question:Why is  such a vector  guaranteed to exist?

Can someone please help me here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you allow a littll analysis to enter into the reasoning, restrict the Raleigh quotient to the unit sphere (this is actually not leading to loss of generality, since it is homogenous of degree 0) which is compact and where the Raleigh quotient is continuous, and therefore attains a maximum value.

Answer (score 1):

The quotient's value is independent of the magnitude of $x$. Thus we can take the max over the unit ball. The unit ball is compact and the function is continuous so it attains its maximum value